# Create a column from a choice of other columns using IF style statement

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following table:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+
| field_a | field_b | which_field |
+---------+---------+-------------+
|       1 |       2 | a           |
|       1 |       2 | b           |
|       3 |       4 | a           |
|       3 |       4 | b           |
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

I'd like to create a column called `output` where the value for each row is taken from either `field_a` or `field_b` based upon the value in `which_field`. So the resulting table would look like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+
| field_a | field_b | which_field | output |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+
|       1 |       2 | a           |      1 |
|       1 |       2 | b           |      2 |
|       3 |       4 | a           |      3 |
|       3 |       4 | b           |      4 |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+
```

I've reviewed a number of examples using `loc` and `np.where` but these only seem to be able to handle assigning a fixed value rather than the value from a choice of columns.

This is an MRE - in reality there could be multiple `which_field` fields so it would be great to get an answer that can cope with multiple conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('which_field', ignore_index=False)

df['output'] = df1.loc[('field_' + df1['which_field']).eq(df1['variable']), 'value']
print (df)
   field_a  field_b which_field  output
0        1        2           a       1
1        1        2           b       2
2        3        4           a       3
3        3        4           b       4
```